# Sufficient Conditions for quasiconcavity proof

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, hessian-matrix

I was reading a book and it says that the sufficient condition for a function to be quasiconcave is that its Bordered Hessian matrix is negative definite. I can't seem to understand this. Please help!

$$
Bordered Hessian=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & f_1 & f_2  \\
    f_1 & f_{11} & f_{12} \\
    f_2 & f_{21} & f_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Due to the $0$ in the (1,1) position, it cannot be negative definite.

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Comment: negative definite matrices have all negative diagonal entries, yes?

Comment: right. If it doesn't at position $(i,i)$, the $i^{th}$ unit vector (all zeros except at position $i$) is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A submatrix of a negative semidefinite matrix is negative semidefinite. Therefore, the hessian itself is negative semidefinite, meaning the function is concave. Any concave function is quasiconcave.